# Pause system in pygame

Tags: python, time, pygame

hi there i've spent hours trying to make a toggle pause in pygame that you press space and it pauses then you press space again to un-pause and i'm having no luck would any one be able to help me please?

```
  ############### 2nd attempt ############# 
 global timedelay

        timedelay = pygame.time.wait (0)
        pause = 0

        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_p  and pause == 0:
                timedelay = pygame.time.wait (9999)
                pause = 1
                if event.key == K_p  and pause == 0:
                    timedelay = pygame.time.wait (0)
                    pause = 0
        timedelay


        ############### 1st attempt #############       
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:   
            pause = 0
            if event.key == K_p and pause == 0:
                while 1: 
                    pause = 0
                    event = pygame.event.wait()
                    pause = 1
                    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == K_p  and pause == 0:
                            print "woo!"
                            pause = 0
                            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't block your whole main loop from running, just skip the state change part of the loop.  You still need to be able to respond to events or your app is "unresponsive". You also want to keep drawing as windows can be moved around and cover your game and the screen still needs to refresh. So:

```
game_over = False
paused = False
while not game_over:
    # handle events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            paused = False
            if event.key == K_p:
                paused = True
        ...
    if not paused:
        # handle game state change
    # handle screen drawing
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: how would I change the game state change? with a wait function like above?

Comment: no, I am talking about your game code.  Generally people break the main game loop into 3 steps, "handle events", "change game state", and "drawing".  You don't want to stop your game from handling events or drawing while paused, you just want what it draws each time to be the same.  So you are skipping your game logic that advances the game. ie. moves character or objects, advances timers, etc

Comment: i was asking how would I get the game to stop? with like the wait function

Comment: `pygame.time.wait()` is sleeping your whole program, this is exactly what I'm saying *not* to do. `pygame.event.wait()` also just sleeps the program until an event is available, not super useful here.  You dont want the program to stop, you want the game to stop advancing.

Comment: ahh so i need to freeze the moving object (Im modifying the snake game btw)

Comment: exactly, while paused you just don't have the snake move and the timer on apples advance(if you have one). but you still process in comming events and draw the screen.